# Refreshing a multi-lined progress bar in R console

Tags: r, printf

I am using the following code to print and update a progress bar to R console in a (bash) terminal:

```
ProgressBar <- function (x, max = 100)
{
    percent <- x / max * 100
    cat(sprintf('\r\t[%-50s] %d%%',
    paste(rep('=', percent / 2), collapse = ''),
    floor(percent)))
    if (x == max)
    cat('\n')
}
```

My question is how to do I do exactly the same thing but with an extra newline underneath the bar that is displayed throughout the updates? Is this possible in a platform independent way?

I tried adding `'\n'` in the end of the first `cat` statement but this prints every update on a new line instead of refreshing the original.

Comment: What aren't you just using the built-in progress bar? http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/txtProgressBar.html

Comment: Because while style 2 does exactly what I want with regards to handling new lines, it is anaesthetic (minor issue) and doesn't display percentage (major issue). Style 3 looks and functions great, but doesn't permit new lines to be printed.

Comment: I'm not really sure what you mean by anaesthetic, but I guess I would suggest modifying the source code for that function to achieve exactly what you want. Anything anyone comes up with here will just be a less sophisticated version of that.

Comment: typo: unaesthetic

But I will try that out. I guess I was hoping for some kind of explanation of why my original attempt didn't work.....